# Spinner: increase/decrease the size of the displayed items

Tags: android, spinner, text-size

I have gone through various posts in stack overflow as to how to change the "text size" of an entry in spinner but none of them seem to be helpful.

I am "templating" my main layout for a galaxy tab 10.1.
So I want my items to be displayed much bigger as on a mobile phone for instance.

Ok, I check around and 90% of peoples talk about android:textSize="....." BUT it does not work for me(???) I do not undertand!

Here is my xml definition:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
    android:prompt="@string/choose_one"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_item" 
/>
```

As you can see it, I added the textSize tag, and even the textAppearance........ without any positiv result..... items stay in a small font, the default one I guess.....

Have an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: the selection view or the display? have you tried to override getDropDownView and/or getView in the adapter yet?

Comment: The display of the list items within the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@android:layout/simple_spinner_item` to render your itens in the `Spinner`, create your own item layout and set the `padding` to give space for selecting the items.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TextView>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_item_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp" >
</TextView>
```

And your spinner using this layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
    android:prompt="@string/choose_one"
    tools:listitem="@layout/your_own_spinner_item" 
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to add layout_height="wrap_content" ?

Comment: Ok, just the same. In fact it reduce the height of the shape/button, but small text size within the selection list still the same.